# What is most simple definition of $p$-divisible group?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

What is most simple definition of $p$-divisible group?

From wikipedia(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barsotti%E2%80%93Tate_group), I have the following definition given by Tate

> A $p$-divisible group of height $h$ (over a scheme $S$) to be an inductive system of groups $G_n$ for $n≥0$, such that $G_n$ is a finite group scheme over $S$ of order $p^n$ and such that $G_n$ is (identified with) the group of elements of order divisible by $p^n$ in $G_{n+1}$.

What does mean by the line "an inductive system of groups $G_n$" above definition?

Does it mean that $p$-divisible group is a category of group $G_n$ whose elements are have order $p$ power?

Can you please explain the definition above?

Comment: Perhaps the definition [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=2ahUKEwjNq-CBrfTmAhUHLFAKHRDWBY4QFjAEegQIBRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uni-bonn.de%2Fag%2Falggeom%2Fveranstaltungen%2FVorlesungen%2F2015ws_vl_morrow%2F2015ws_vl_p-div%2520final.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1OycMzq8eHfxV7JYb_cRTx) on page $18$ is better for you. At least, the author Matthew Morrow has $18$ pages before the definition to explain everything properly. You should read this before asking more.

Comment: Things which mimic $\{ z\in (\overline{K}^*)^h, \exists n, z^{p^n}=1\}$ in the sense of $S$-schemes

Comment: @DietrichBurde, thank you

Comment: @reuns, thank you